# Conditional routing in Nifi

Tags: mongodb, apache, rabbitmq, apache-nifi

I am fetching some data from GetFile processor and currently sending it to mongoDB and rabbitMQ both using PutmongoRecord and PublishAMQP processors respectively.

I want to make this conditional, like say reading an attribute from some file that has the value "mongo" then I should be able to only push it to mongoDB and not rabbitMQ.

I read about RouteOnAttribute processor but not sure how it will work in my case. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to read an attribute (column) from the `flowfile` and based on the value want to route to **`PutmongoRecord and PublishAMQP`**

**`Method-1:(preferred)`**

You can try [PartitionRecord](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html) processor and then processor adds the partition field value to the flowfile.

Then by using **`RouteOnAttribute`** Processor you can dynamically pass the flowfile to Mongo and AMQP processors.

***Flow:***

```
1.GetFile
2.PartitionRecord //define record reader and writer controller services
3.RouteOnAttribute //add new properties to route mongo and amqp then fork
4.1 PutMongoRecord 4.2 PublishAMQP
```

***(or)***

**`Method-2:`**

Another way would be by using [RouteOnContent](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/139243/nifiusing-routeoncontent-for-filtering-responses.html) then add new properties to identify the records that goes to Mongo and AMQP.

- Use the `property relationships` to connect to **`PutmongoRecord and PublishAMQP`** processors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add *dynamic properties* to the `RouteOnAttribute` processor that compare the incoming flowfile attributes with the expected values (using literal equality or string operations), and drag each outgoing relationship to the desired follow-on processor. [This page](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54811/redirecting-flow-based-on-certain-condition-nifi.html) has an example.